# Angular hiding mat-table causes actives of undefined error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to add a condition where the table should only show the table if table !== undefined and table has data but hiding the table causes the error.

The condition I am trying to implement is if table !== undefined and table.datasource.data is not empty or null and tableOptions.notifications is falsed show table

else if table !== undefined and table.datasource.data is empty and tableOptions.notifications is true then hide table else show

Any idea guys ? Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4Z2b.png)

#error

```
core.js:6162 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'actives' of undefined
    at MatMultiSortTableDataSource.orderData (ngx-mat-multi-sort.js:795)
    at TableData._clientSideSort (ngx-mat-multi-sort.js:428)
    at TableData.set data [as data] (ngx-mat-multi-sort.js:479)
    at TableMultiSortComponent.getData (table-multi-sort.component.ts:62)
    at table-multi-sort.component.ts:51
    at timer (zone-evergreen.js:2561)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:406)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28497)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:405)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:178)
```

#html code

```
<mat-card *ngIf="table !== undefined">
  <div style="padding-top: 12px;" *ngIf="tableOptions.notifications">
    <div class="alertInfo" >
      <mat-icon>{{tableOptions.notifications[0].type}}</mat-icon>{{tableOptions.notifications[0].message}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <mat-table  mat-table [dataSource]="table.dataSource" matMultiSort (matSortChange)="table.onSortEvent()"> 
    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of table.columns" [matColumnDef]="column.id">
      <mat-header-cell class="table-multi-sort-header" *matHeaderCellDef [mat-multi-sort-header]="column.id"> 
        <div>{{column.name}}</div> 
        <div class="sub-text">{{getColumnSubtitle(column.id)}}</div>
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <ng-container *ngIf="column.id !== 'action'; then col; else actionCol"></ng-container>
          <ng-template #col>
            <app-table-multi-sort-cell-default [cellData]="row" [id]="column.id" [subId]="getColumnSubId(column.id)"></app-table-multi-sort-cell-default>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template #actionCol>
            <app-table-multi-sort-cell-action [rowData]="row" [actions]="getActions(column.id)" (actionClickEvent)="clickTableAction($event,row)"></app-table-multi-sort-cell-action>
          </ng-template>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="table.displayedColumns; sticky:true"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let item; columns: table.displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table> 
  <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="isLoading" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
</mat-card>
```

#ts code

```
export class TableMultiSortComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() tableOptions:any;
  @Input() tableMessage:any;
  @Input() tableData:any = [];

  test = 0;
  @Input() isClientSide:boolean = false;
  @Input() isLoading: boolean = false;
  @Output() tableActionsEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() dataServiceEvent = new EventEmitter<any>() ;
  @ViewChild(MatMultiSort, { static: false }) sort: MatMultiSort;
  hasInfoMessage: boolean;
  tableConfig: any = TABLE_MULTI_SORT_OPTIONS.DEFAULT;
  table:TableData<any>;
  displayedColumns: any;
  
  constructor() { }
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {   
    this.initTableMultiSort();
  }

  initTableMultiSort() {
    this.tableConfig = {
      ...this.tableConfig,
      ...this.tableOptions
    }
    
    this.table = new TableData<any>(this.tableConfig.columns,this.tableConfig.sortParams);
    this.table.pageSize = this.tableConfig.pageSize;
    this.table.pageIndex = this.tableConfig.pageIndex;
    this.table.nextObservable.subscribe(() => { this.getData(); });
    this.table.sortObservable.subscribe(() => { this.getData(); });
    this.table.previousObservable.subscribe(() => { this.getData(); });
    this.table.sizeObservable.subscribe(() => { this.getData(); });

    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.table.dataSource = new MatMultiSortTableDataSource(this.sort, this.isClientSide);
      this.getData();
      console.log("this.tabl1e", this.table)

    },0);
  }
  getData(){
    this.table.totalElements = 1;
    this.table.pageIndex = 0;
    this.table.totalElements = 0;
    this.table.pageSize = 10;

    this.table.data = this.tableData;

    if(this.dataServiceEvent) {
      this.dataServiceEvent.emit(this.table);
    }
  }
  getColumnSubtitle(id) :string{    
    return this.tableOptions.columns.filter(c => c.id === id)[0].subtitle;
  }

  getColumnSubId(id) :string{
    return this.tableOptions.columns.filter(c => c.id === id)[0].subId;
  }

  getActions(id):any{
    return this.tableOptions.columns.filter(c => c.id === id)[0].actions;
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXAGg.png)

Comment: If the input `tableData` is the source, why not check if null before calling `initTableMultiSort()`?

Comment: What do you mean Sir , can you please ellaborate ? Thanks.

Comment: can you share the content of `table-multi-sort.component.ts:62`  and  `table-multi-sort.component.ts:51` as of the error message thats were your problem starts

Comment: Hi , please check my updated question , @EricKrg This is the content https://imgur.com/a/H46WoMW

Comment: What is the `TableMultiSortComponent` selector? In which other component do you use it?

Comment: selector: 'app-table-multi-sort', it is used as reusable table

Comment: @RajivKumar that is not what i meant, the error message show that the error you get is invoked by line 51 and 62 in table-multi-sort.component.ts

Comment: Where you use that selector why not use a `*ngIf` like: `<app-table-multi-sort *ngIf="tableData"></app-table-multi-sort>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the table you shouldn't even instantiate the `TableMultiSortComponent` component.
Assuming the selector for that component is `app-table-multi-sort` you should add a `*ngIf` to it like:

```
<app-table-multi-sort *ngIf="tableData"></app-table-multi-sort>
```

Comment: here is how I use the selector  <app-table-multi-sort *ngIf="data" (dataServiceEvent)="dataForApprovalServiceEvent($event)" [tableOptions]="tableOptions"
        [tableData]="data"></app-table-multi-sort>

Comment: So if `data` is undefined the component is not instantiate and you don't have a problem. Right?

Comment: The problem when I do that is when there is new data it is showing an error core.js:6162 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'pageIndex' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (deals-approval.component.ts:42)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at BehaviorSubject.next (Subject.js:39)
    at BehaviorSubject.next (BehaviorSubject.js:30)
    at deals-transaction.component.ts:174
    at timer (zone-evergreen.js:2561)

Comment: the error still occurs when hiding the selector

Comment: But that is a different error in a different component it seems.